# i want to integrate gmail and yahoo with my android app

Tags: android

I am working with gmail and yahoo in my android app, I need full a sample project in which gmail has been used. simply i click on gmail login button it should goes to the gmail login page then authenticate and callback to my android app

Comment: if you are supposing that we'll give you spoon filled with cooked food buddy... No No No...

Comment: as u wish if u dont want to help me.....thanks for ur time

Comment: if you just put this line "integrate gmail with android" to google you can find a lot of samples.

Comment: i did this, i am new to android so i did not get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [K-9 mail](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9). K-9 is an opensource email client based on the Email application shipped with the initial release of Android.

Comment: i dont need k9mail permita.. i need gmail and yahoo with app....anyway thanks for ur time

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're interested in **Single Sign On**?  Using **OAuth** perhaps?

These are the options for authenticating your app using a GMail/Google Apps account:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Authentication

Here is how to acquire the user via the **AccountManager** API:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager

Here's an example that takes you all the way to pulling data from a Google API:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/04/12/oauth-android-google-apis-client-library-java/

Answer (score 0):

Do following,

```
public void sendGmail(Activity activity, String subject, String text)   
 {   
     Intent gmailIntent = new Intent();   
     gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");  
     gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);  
     gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);  
    try {  
      activity.startActivity(gmailIntent);  
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex)  {  
      // handle error
    }  
}
```